# Class 'GoogleSession' not found when using composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm using the [google-trends](https://github.com/jonasva/google-trends) library and installed it with composer

```
composer update jonasva/google-trends
```

my `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "jonasva/google-trends": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

I included the file `start.php` in the main folder:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$config = [
    'email' =>  'myemail@gmail.com',
    'password' =>  'mypass',
];

$session = (new GoogleSession($config))->authenticate();

$response = (new GoogleTrendsRequest($session))
    ->setDateRange(new \DateTime('2014-02-01'), new \DateTime()) // date range, if not passed, the past year will be used by default
    ->setLocation('BE') // For location Belgium
    ->getTopQueries() // cid (top queries)
    ->send(); //execute the request

$data = $response->getTermsObjects(); // return an array of GoogleTrendsTerm objects
```

But I get

> Fatal error: Class 'GoogleSession' not found in

Should I include files other than `vendor/autoload.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author conveniently didn't mention the fact that the *actual* fully qualified class name is `Jonasva\GoogleTrends\GoogleSession`.

`use Jonasva\GoogleTrends\GoogleSession;` at the top of your file.
Check the source code of the library to figure out such information.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use FQDN. Namespace + Classname

```
$session = (new Jonasva\GoogleTrends\GoogleSession($config))->authenticate();
```